# Concatenating two lists of different types with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to concat two list that are of different types?

```
string[] left = { "A", "B", "C" };
int[] right = { 1, 2, 3 };
var result = left.Concat(right);
```

The code above obciously has a type error. It works if the types match (eg. both are ints or strings).

pom

Comment: I would imagine that this is not possible in general but for a scenario like your example, you could easily transform the int list to a string list and concatenate them.

Comment: what is your expected result (i.e. what type is `result`)?

Answer (score 15):

You can box it.

```
var result = left.Cast<object>().Concat(right.Cast<object>());
```

`result` will be `IEnumerable<object>`.

Then to unbox it, you can use `OfType<T>()`.

```
var myStrings = result.OfType<string>();
var myInts = result.OfType<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cast both to a common base type (in this case `object`), or you could convert the types of one of the lists so you can combine them, either:

```
right.Select(i = i.ToString())
```

or

```
left.Select(s => int.Parse(s)) // Careful of exceptions here!
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way I know to make this work would be:

```
var result = left.Concat(right.Select(i = i.ToString()));
```