# Bundling 2 lists of different type objects and returning that bundle in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I would like to bundle 2 lists of different type objects and return that bundle. If I were able to bundle these two lists, how would I be able to unbundle them?

```
public List<List<T>> bundleLists(List<Obj1> obj1, List<Obj2> obj2){
    List<List<T>> bundle = new List<List<T>>();
    bundle.add(obj1);
    bundle.add(obj2);
    return bundle;
}
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190701/concatenating-two-lists-of-different-types-with-linq exact solution that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397914.aspx

Take a look at linq. You can transform your two lists into one by using a join.

Comment: Sometimes i handled this situation writing a class which will have two different properties of type List<T1> and List<T2> and retuns the class after assigned